# VBA/JSON Parse Json data from arrays

Tags: json, vba

Im trying to parse Data from a json object with several arrays. 
This code as an Example:

```
    {
  "Version": "1.0",
  "I.1": [
    {
      "MethodenID": "I.1.3",
      "Ranking": "1",
      "Punktzahl": "20"
    },
    {
      "MethodenID": "I.1.1",
      "Ranking": "3",
      "Punktzahl": "68"
    }
  ],
  "I.2": [
    {
      "MethodenID": "I.2.2",
      "Ranking": "1",
      "Punktzahl": "87"
    },
    {
      "MethodenID": "I.2.1",
      "Ranking": "2",
      "Punktzahl": "67"
    }
  ]}
```

I want to get only the objects from the inner arrays. 
I tried the power query tool excel has but ran into some problems having to access every inner list seperately.

After that i tried my luck with vba but had the same problem.

My Question now is: Is it possible at all to do this with vba?

If not is it somehow possible to convert the file into a more readable state?

I tried out the JsonConverter https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON already.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd

        .Title = "Select a json file"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show() Then
            ws.Cells(1, 200) = "1"
            Filename = (.SelectedItems(1))
            Dim content As String
            Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile

            Open Filename For Input As #iFile

                content = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
                'MsgBox (content)
                'Parse JSON String
                Dim products As Object
                Set products = JsonConverter.ParseJson(content)
                i = 1
                For Each Product In products
                    ws.Cells(i, 1) = Product("MethodenID")
                    ws.Cells(i, 2) = Product("Ranking")
                    ws.Cells(i, 3) = Product("Punktzahl")
                    i = i + 1
                Next

            Close #iFile
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

I came up with this from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fukOV0hG4eU&t=363s
Sadly i dont seem to be able to get to the values in the inner arrays.

Comment: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: There is a VBA JSON parser module you can use: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: forgot some vital information regarding the converter. edited the question

Comment: `products` is a scripting dictionary with keys "I.1" and "I.2", each of which will return a Collection with two items, which are in turn dictionary objects representing the object you want to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim k, arr
Dim Json As Object

'reading json from a worksheet cell...
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Range("C3").Value)

For Each k In Array("I.1", "I.2")
    Set arr = Json(k) 'arr here is a VBA Collection object
    For Each o In arr 'o here is a scripting dictionary
        Debug.Print o("MethodenID"), o("Ranking"), o("Punktzahl")
    Next o
Next k
```